# passing a variable from a function defined outside the loop but called inside that loop

Tags: php, function, loops

i want to call a function which is defined outside the loop but called inside the loop and then access a variable from that function definition which is outside the loop to inside the loop every time loop runs
here is the database connectivity that contains while loop and a funtion calling and then accessing the $second_trim variable defined in ""function page($h)""  inside the while loop

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <title></title>
 </head>     
 <body>
 <?php
 $getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");
 while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery))
 {
 $title = $runrows ['Title'];
 $url = $runrows ['URL'];
 page($url);
 echo "<div style='clear: both;position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:   white;'>
 $second_trim</div>";
}
function page($h){
$i=fopen($h,"r");
$contents=stream_get_contents($i);
fclose($i);
$contents=strtolower($contents);

$start='<div';

$start_pos=strpos($contents,$start);
$first_trim=substr($contents,$start_pos);

$stop='</div>';
$stop_pos=strpos($first_trim,$stop);

$second_trim=substr($first_trim,0,$stop_pos);
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

the while loop fetch url from the database and pass through "page($url)" function called inside the loop to defined function "function page($h)"outside the loop it will get required content in $second_trim that will displayed inside the loop in echo statement every time it runs but i m getting the error like 
    Fatal error: Call to undefined function crawl_page() 
their is some syntax problem i m facing that i cant find after alot of search is their any can do this plz help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define your function -> `function page($h){...}` before your loop. Second, return the `$second_trim` at the end of your function, and third set your function call to your variable

```
...your html...
<?php

function page($h){
      $i=fopen($h,"r");
      $contents=stream_get_contents($i);
      fclose($i);
      $contents=strtolower($contents);
      $start='<div';
      $start_pos=strpos($contents,$start);
      $first_trim=substr($contents,$start_pos);   
      $stop='</div>';
      $stop_pos=strpos($first_trim,$stop);
      $second_trim=substr($first_trim,0,$stop_pos);

      //return the value
      return $second_trim;
}


$getquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE $construct LIMIT $start, $per_page");
while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($getquery)){
      $title = $runrows ['Title'];
      $url = $runrows ['URL'];

      //save the function returned value to variable
      $second_trim = page($url);

      echo "<div style='clear: both;position:relative;border:1px solid #A5BEBE;background-color:   white;'>
      $second_trim</div>";
}
?>
...your html...
```

Comment: gud 1 this concept removed that error but its showing two another error but thanks i dint know that method .... the new errors are......Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 68

Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource in C:\wamp\www\search.php on line 69

Comment: for `Warning: stream_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given` -> [`stream_get_contents() - Returns a string or FALSE on failure.`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stream-get-contents.php). So your `stream_get_contents()` is failing. You will need to figure out why. The second warning - `Warning: fclose(): supplied argument is not a valid stream resource` is related to the first, and should go away when you fix the first.

Comment: heyy i get the error its just fetching the null value of $url from database sorry! that was my fault i've filled it now and its working pretty good now thanks man u gave me proper logic it was really important for me big applause for u :D :D

Comment: heyy if u r there then help me again its working good but not the way i want ...... its showing div tag inside a div but i want it to be created discretely but it is creating div inside a div which is not required i want to display all echo statements containing  divs inside the loop once and next tym when loop increments the whole echo statements  containing divs should be created on the next line not inside that previous divs i've tried this many times but not getting proper logic.... if u can do this then plz help me out